# Oracle Driver: Framework 3.5 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, frameworks

I am working with Framework 3.5 and C#. The projects need to acces to Oracle database.

My problem is when I installed the client of Oracle I has the ODP for Framework 2 or 4.

Which Oracle driver I have to use for Framework 3.5?

I cant change the framework. Do exists Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for framework 3.5?

In concret i am building a web api to access to the database.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use version 2. If you like to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver then you have to change the Framework version to 4 or higher.

For Framework version below 4 you can use only the Unmanaged Driver.